# Shopify "mailto:" tag issue

Tags: javascript, php, shopify, shopify-app

I am having issue of external link in shopify store.

I am injecting script through my app for displaying a bubble with anchor tag for redirecting user to given link. But shopify is changing the anchor tag to the following link as mentioned below:-

```
 <a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#076e69616847736274732964686a"><span style="color:#999999;">??Click here </span></a>
```

And this link cause to 404 error and page not found.

This is my js code

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js';
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag)
} else {
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict()
}
var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
jqTag.src = '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.5.2/lib/js/emojione.min.js';
headTag.appendChild(jqTag)

$(document).ready(function(){
    var shop_name = Shopify.shop;
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://deepak.com/client/ajax_response.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{store_name:shop_name},
        success:function(data){
            if(data != '0'){
                $('body').append(data);
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('Network error');
        }
    })
});
```

and response returned is

```
<div id="bubbleChatBox"><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#c5acaba3aa85b1a0b6b1eba6aaa8"><span style="color:#999999;">Click here </span></a>
</div><script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script>
```

And I have not added email-decode.min.js but it is being added automatically to my response.

The link should display correctly like this (Desired Result):-

```
<a href="mailto:info@test.com"><span style="color:#999999;">Click here </span></a>
```

Please help me.

Comment: we need your code

Comment: @Deepak Lakhara may be some other app js will change...I just guess

Comment: @delboy1978uk Please look to my code.

Comment: none of that code looks related to the generation of that `<a>` tag.

Comment: What is `https://deepak.com/client/ajax_response.php` - is that a URL pointing to some sort of shopify functionality, or something you have written yourself? If the latter, then what exactly are you doing in this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get how to resolve the issue with Shopify. But a trick made my code working.

I just change the "mailto" to "@mailto" while saving in database and After injecting script on shopify store. I changed the "@mailto" to "mailto" and it worked.

I used the following code to make it working.

```
<script>
    $("#bubbleChatBox a").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).attr("href");
        $(this).attr("href",text.replace("@mailto", "mailto"));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Shopify so unfortunately I cannot test this, but it seems that this is something that is handled by the server. A workaround may be to do the following:

1. In your `success:` function, after `$('body').append(data);` add the following:

   ```
   document.getElementById('bubbleChatBox').childNodes[0].setAttribute("href", "mailto:info@test.com");
   ```

This uses Javascript to load your desired HTML into the document AFTER it is processed by the server and received by the client. Please let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for response.
Link is being created by this :- 
http://prntscr.com/l4ty4r
I can ask user to add like this.So what other solution can i apply.

Comment: Sorry, I can not ask client to do with div and above patter.

Comment: @Deepak Lakhara: After you posted your code, I realized that you cannot add that element. Try my edited solution and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the store is behind Cloudflare and using their [Email Address Obfuscation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-) feature. This can be disabled in the Cloudflare control panel, or on a case-by-case basis using these tags:

```
<!--email_off--><a href="mailto:foo@bar.test"></a><!--/email_off-->
```